# Download EXTJS locking grid as PDF on button click

Tags: javascript, pdf, extjs, extjs4, extjs4.1

I am using EXTJS 4.1. I have created an EXTJS 4.1 locking grid.Now i want to implement the functionality of downloading the grid in PDF form(may be in form of a table) when user clicks on the download button.How to export ext js grid to PDF?

```
   <html>
        <head>
            <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
            <title id='title'>HTML Page setup Tutorial</title>       
            <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="ext-all.css" />       
            <script type="text/javascript" src="ext-all.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
    Ext.onReady(function() {
        Ext.QuickTips.init()

        // sample static data for the store
        var myData = [
            ['3m Co',                               71.72, 0.02,  0.03,  '9/1 12:00am'],
            ['Alcoa Inc',                           29.01, 0.42,  1.47,  '9/1 12:00am'],
            ['Altria Group Inc',                    83.81, 0.28,  0.34,  '9/1 12:00am'],
            ['American Express Company',            52.55, 0.01,  0.02,  '9/1 12:00am'],
            ['American International Group, Inc.',  64.13, 0.31,  0.49,  '9/1 12:00am'],
            ['AT&T Inc.',                           31.61, -0.48, -1.54, '9/1 12:00am'],
            ['Boeing Co.',                          75.43, 0.53,  0.71,  '9/1 12:00am'],
            ['Caterpillar Inc.',                    67.27, 0.92,  1.39,  '9/1 12:00am'],
            ['Citigroup, Inc.',                     49.37, 0.02,  0.04,  '9/1 12:00am'],
            ['E.I. du Pont de Nemours and Company', 40.48, 0.51,  1.28,  '9/1 12:00am'],
            ['Exxon Mobil Corp',                    68.1,  -0.43, -0.64, '9/1 12:00am'],
            ['General Electric Company',            34.14, -0.08, -0.23, '9/1 12:00am'],
            ['General Motors Corporation',          30.27, 1.09,  3.74,  '9/1 12:00am'],
            ['Hewlett-Packard Co.',                 36.53, -0.03, -0.08, '9/1 12:00am'],
            ['Honeywell Intl Inc',                  38.77, 0.05,  0.13,  '9/1 12:00am'],
            ['Intel Corporation',                   19.88, 0.31,  1.58,  '9/1 12:00am'],
            ['International Business Machines',     81.41, 0.44,  0.54,  '9/1 12:00am'],
            ['Johnson & Johnson',                   64.72, 0.06,  0.09,  '9/1 12:00am'],
            ['JP Morgan & Chase & Co',              45.73, 0.07,  0.15,  '9/1 12:00am'],
            ['McDonald\'s Corporation',             36.76, 0.86,  2.40,  '9/1 12:00am'],
            ['Merck & Co., Inc.',                   40.96, 0.41,  1.01,  '9/1 12:00am'],
            ['Microsoft Corporation',               25.84, 0.14,  0.54,  '9/1 12:00am'],
            ['Pfizer Inc',                          27.96, 0.4,   1.45,  '9/1 12:00am'],
            ['The Coca-Cola Company',               45.07, 0.26,  0.58,  '9/1 12:00am'],
            ['The Home Depot, Inc.',                34.64, 0.35,  1.02,  '9/1 12:00am'],
            ['The Procter & Gamble Company',        61.91, 0.01,  0.02,  '9/1 12:00am'],
            ['United Technologies Corporation',     63.26, 0.55,  0.88,  '9/1 12:00am'],
            ['Verizon Communications',              35.57, 0.39,  1.11,  '9/1 12:00am'],
            ['Wal-Mart Stores, Inc.',               45.45, 0.73,  1.63,  '9/1 12:00am']
        ];

        /**
         * Custom function used for column renderer
         * @param {Object} val
         */
        function change(val) {
            if (val > 0) {
                return '<span style="color:green;">' + val + '</span>';
            } else if (val < 0) {
                return '<span style="color:red;">' + val + '</span>';
            }
            return val;
        }

        /**
         * Custom function used for column renderer
         * @param {Object} val
         */
        function pctChange(val) {
            if (val > 0) {
                return '<span style="color:green;">' + val + '%</span>';
            } else if (val < 0) {
                return '<span style="color:red;">' + val + '%</span>';
            }
            return val;
        }

        // create the data store
        var store = Ext.create('Ext.data.ArrayStore', {

            fields: [
               {name: 'company'},
               {name: 'price',      type: 'float'},
               {name: 'change',     type: 'float'},
               {name: 'pctChange',  type: 'float'},
               {name: 'lastChange', type: 'date', dateFormat: 'n/j h:ia'}
            ],
            data: myData




        });




        // create the Grid
          var grid1 = Ext.create('Ext.grid.Panel', {
             renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
            store: store,
            width:0.3*Ext.getBody().getViewSize().width,
            height: 0.5*Ext.getBody().getViewSize().height,
            columnLines: true,
            columns: [{
                text     : 'Company',
                locked   : true,
                sortable : false,
                dataIndex: 'company',
    renderer : function (value, metaData, record, row, col, store, gridView) {
                metaData.tdAttr = 'data-qtip="' + value + '"';
                return value;
            }

            },{
                text     : 'Price',
                width    : 125,
                locked:true,
                sortable : true,
                renderer : 'usMoney',
                dataIndex: 'price',

            },{
                text     : 'Change',
                width    : 555,
                sortable : true,

                dataIndex: 'change',
                renderer : function (value, metaData, record, row, col, store, gridView) {
                metaData.tdAttr = 'data-qtip="' + value + '"';

                return value;
            }

            },{
                text     : '% Change',
                width    : 555,
                sortable : true,
                renderer : pctChange,
                dataIndex: 'pctChange',

            },{
                text     : 'Last Updated',
                width    : 555,
                sortable : true,
                renderer : Ext.util.Format.dateRenderer('m/d/Y'),
                dataIndex: 'lastChange'
            }],


            title: 'Locking Grid Column',
            selType: 'cellmodel',
             selModel: Ext.create('MyApp.MultiCellSelectionModel',{
                            mode: 'MULTI',
                            allowDeselect: true
                     }),
               multiSelect: true,
               listeners : {
                    cellclick( grid, cell, columnIndex, record , node , rowIndex , evt){

                        var cellId = grid.getHeaderCt().getHeaderAtIndex(columnIndex).id;
                        var dataIndex = grid.getHeaderCt().getHeaderAtIndex(columnIndex).dataIndex; 

                        var text = grid.getHeaderCt().getHeaderAtIndex(columnIndex).text; 

                        alert(dataIndex);
                        alert(text);
                    }                   


                    }

        });



    });



    </script>
      </head>
        <body>

        </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: You gotta do that on Server Side

Comment: @JChap Can't i do that using JSPDF on client side?

Comment: I have used [pdfmake](https://github.com/bpampuch/pdfmake) before to do exactly this. Alas I can't share the code, it is proprietary.

Comment: @NielsHeisterkamp could you give a fiddle for my code using pdfmake which converts the grid into PDF format?...please help me out....or a normal html table with colspan and rowspan that can be downloaded in PDF format?

Comment: I'm sorry but this is not a trivial problem, but using the pdfMake documentation you should be able to figure it out.